# RAD does not prompt for worksapce

Tags: workspace, ibm-rad

When I open RAD it does not prompt for workspace. I verified in Preference=>General=>Startup and shutdown=>Prompt for workspace check box is checked. But still it does not prompt while start up. Any ideas how to get RAD to prompt for the workspace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma

I am surprised that setting the preferences has not worked.

It always works for me on my eclipse and RAD(and other eclipse based tools like WID).

The file(org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs) is where these preferences are persisited in teh file system.

Look for this under this directory
\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

I am not showing the entire file here (as that is just a clutter). Look at the SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG and ensure that it's value is true.

MAX_RECENT_WORKSPACES=5

**SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true**

eclipse.preferences.version=1

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : Run RAD as administrator.

Long answer:
I faced the same problem on my computer. I believe the issue is that I didn't run RAD as administrator.

Even though eclipse clearly shows that YES, it will prompt me for a workspace, the content of the property file remained :
SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=false

On Windows 7, you need administrator privilege to write files to the "Program Files" directory. This would explain why RAD was never able to overwrite the file with my new preferences.

Running RAD as administrator is how I managed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run RAD

1. Go to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces
2. Check the box "Prompt for workspace on startup"
3. Save your settings and restart RAD